# PHP unlink denied on localhost / windows

Tags: php, windows, image, directory, unlink

In portuguese language we use an expression to tell what's going on which is:

> this is witchcraft

So, I'm trying to unlink an image, and while I'm writing this topic I'm thinking about the possibility of `<img src='url'/>` means that the image is open (?).

I have an html table with two columns.

```
#        |     Image
Delete      Image here displayed
Delete      Image here displayed
etc..       etc...
```

By clicking "Delete", an AJAX function is performed.

```
$(".delete").on('click', function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'inc/response.php?type=deleteImage',
        data: {id: $(this).attr('id')},
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            parent.remove();
        }
    });
});
```

And the code for `deleteImage` is the following:

```
$path = "../images/videos/" . $image->get($_REQUEST['id']);
```

This **returns perfectly** the path.

```
unlink($path);
```

If the path is incorrect the php log returns:

> Error on unlink because file or directory does not exists..

, but the message I'm getting is

> PHP Warning:
>
> unlink(../images/videos/): Permission denied in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\newproject\inc\response.php

Since I'm working locally and it's windows, I've set the right administration rights for the folder.
Btw, the folder has the following structure:

```
images 
   > Videos
         > customer_A
         > customer_B
         > customer_C
```

[image]

The **Total Control flag** is set for EVERY user.

So, what am I doing wrong? Can the problem be because of the image is "open" in the `<img src>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to remove `../images/videos/` directory. It seems your `$image->get($_REQUEST['id'])` returns empty.

Comment: You are right. Plus, let me add that the problem is that I was deleting the ID from the database BEFORE deleting from the folder. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Could you mark this answer accepted to let other people see & not waste time

Comment: Yes, I was just waiting for the minutes to pass. :)