# Warning: unlink(user_images/): Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\foreign\user Profile.php on line 177

Tags: php

**Warning: unlink(user_images/): Permission denied in C:.How to solve unlike permission denied**

```
if($imgFile)
    {
      $upload_dir = 'user_images/'; // upload directory 
      $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension
      $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid extensions
      $userpic = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;
      if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions))
      {     
        if($imgSize < 5000000)
        {
          unlink($upload_dir.$edit_row['userPic']);
          move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$upload_dir.$userpic);
        }
        else
        {
          $errMSG = "Sorry, your file is too large it should be less then 5MB";
        }
 }
```

Comment: You need to set read/write permission on the directory.

Comment: how to do that can you explain it

Answer (score 0):

Permission denied error happens because you're trying to delete a file without having enough/right permissions for doing that. Please see following two similar questions

[How to get permission to use unlink()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148229/how-to-get-permission-to-use-unlink)

[PHP unlink denied on localhost / windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22644060/php-unlink-denied-on-localhost-windows)